# Can I give both an if and else statement another if and else statement?

Tags: python-3.8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pqm1.png)

So I am making a adventure game where you can choose your own path, but I don't know how I can assign the next row of options to one of the first two options and another row of options to the other option in the first option (look at picture for clearer understanding). So if you first choose plane, you get the two options for plane, but if you choose car, you get the options for car. But I don't know how to do that.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Please avoid posting code as images or links. You can copy-paste directly to the question and format it as code (by selecting and pressing ctrl+k)

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to programing @Valentinj.

You should use additional variables.

```py
engine = input('plane/car')

if engine == 'plane':
  direction = input('fly/go_back')
  if direction == 'fly':
    ...
  if direction == 'go_back':
    ...

if engine == 'car':
  place = input('city/treasure')
  if place == 'city':
    ...
  if place == 'treasure':
    ...
```